# Shared resources for different ResourceControllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonapi-resources

`jsonapi-utils` (`jsonapi-resources`) requires a serializer (resource) for each `ResourceController`

Example

```rb
class FooController < JsonapiController
  def create
    # some code
  end
end

class BarController < JsonapiController
  def create
    # some code
  end
end
```

In this example `BarController` should use `FooResource`. Is it possible to define the serializer?

Comment: I don't know if there is a less hacky way but you could define `def resource_klass_name; 'FooResource'; end;` in `BarController` This will override the original implementation [Source](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/eb432722b915e76914be9132e010a1244a32e91c/lib/jsonapi/acts_as_resource_controller.rb#L164)

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the class manually by implementing [the `resource_class` method](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/eb432722b915e76914be9132e010a1244a32e91c/lib/jsonapi/acts_as_resource_controller.rb#L164):

```
class BarController < JsonapiController
  def create
    # some code
  end

  private

  def resource_klass
    @resource_class ||= FooResource
  end
end
```